# Оборот "пока, во всяком случае"

Tags: пунктуация

Выделяется запятыми или нет?

В интернете можно встретить оба варианта. И в пользу каждого есть свои аргументы. Понятно, что вложенный оборот "во всяком случае" запятыми выделяется. Но нужна ли ещё одна запятая перед "пока"? Контекст обычно такой: некие предпринятые меры не привели к ожидаемому результату. Если просто добавить слово "пока" после "привели", то запятые вокруг него поставить не хочется. А вот если к нему прилепить ещё и вложенный оборот "во всяком случае", то сразу хочется поставить запятую и перед "пока", поскольку там появляется интонационная пауза.

**UPD:** Вижу, что выразил вопрос не совсем удачно. Про присоединительные конструкции я даже не думал, поскольку исхожу из того, что в них должно быть какое-то собственное содержание. Я же имел в виду именно речевой оборот, который вставляется исключительно по стилистическим соображениям. Для ясности приведу два примера.

1) "Реформы образования в нашей стране не привели пока к положительным результатам"
(Это говорит сторонник реформ. Суть высказанного в том, что реформы нужно продолжить и ускорить.)

2) "Реформы образования в нашей стране не привели, пока, к положительным результатам"
(Это говорит противник реформ. Суть высказанного в том, что эти реформы не могут привести к положительным результатам, и поэтому их нужно срочно сворачивать. Слово "пока" говорящий выделяет интонационно, вкладывая в него всю иронию, которую только можно вложить в одно слово.)

С одним словом всё просто. Если выделяется интонационно, то значит ставим запятые. Но что делать, если есть ещё и конструкция "во всяком случае"? При этом смысл имеется в виду первый (не ирония). Ставить ещё одну запятую для выделения многословного речевого оборота не хочется - слишком много запятых. Кроме того, из-за запятой можно подумать, что имеется в виду ироничный смысл. Но и без запятой плохо, поскольку интонационная пауза всё-таки делается. Сейчас мне уже кажется, что можно выделить оборот при помощи двух тире. Но я не могу найти подтверждение тому, что такое допустимо.

Comment: Что ещё за оборот такой?  
"Во всяком случае" обычно обычно не обособляется, если это член предложения, иначе - обособляется, но "слово" пока к этому обороту относиться не может.
Фразу приведите целиком.






Comment: Пришлось заминусовать. 
Автор окончательно потерял чувство реальности. И чувство меры.

Comment: См. тему "Вставные конструкции"

Comment: Посмотрел. Там первым делом сказано о том, что такие конструкции несут смысловую нагрузку, а не стилистическую.

Comment: А у Вас что, бессмысленная  вставка, разве? А про стиль...Я думаю, он здесь ни при чем. Важен не стиль, а форма речи. Вставные конструкции часто употребляются в устной речи.

Comment: Её смысл не в ней самой. Она играет стилистическую роль. Понятно, что в устной речи тоже употребляют содержательные вставки. Но при чём тут вообще вставки? Интересен случай риторического оборота, когда слово "пока" подчёркивается интонационно. Специально для того, чтобы все поняли, что это туфта, и никакой надежды на успех в будущем на самом деле нет. В общем, понятно. Мой вопрос не понят. Даже после уточнения.

Comment: См. Вставные конструкции. Ваше "пока", даже когда оно одиночное, это вставная конструкция. 

Вставные конструкции – это... См. дополнения в ответе .

Comment: Всё понятно. Вы отрицаете возможность того, что это может быть речевым оборотом.

Answer (score 5):

МОжно поставить  запятую,  можно - точку. Это присоединительная конструкция.

**Добавляю**. Конструирую предложение, как я поняла. 
*Предпринятые меры не привели -  пока, во всяком случае, -   к ожидаемому результату*. 
**Пока, во всяком случае,   - вставная конструкция**. Можно выделить запятыми, но, чтобы не было нагромождения, лучше тире или скобками.

*Предпринятые меры не привели   к ожидаемому результату, пока, во всяком случае.*
**Пока, во всяком случае – присоединительная конструкция**. Ставим запятую или точку.*Предпринятые меры не привели к ожидаемому результату. Пока, во всяком случае.*

**Дополняю.**
Вставные конструкции – это

(вставочные) слова, словосочетания и предложения, содержащие различного рода добавочные замечания, попутные указания, уточнения, поправки, разъясняющие предложение в целом или отдельное слово в нем, иногда резко выпадающие из синтаксической структуры целого. В отличие от вводных конструкций, вставные конструкции не выражают модальных значений, не содержат указания на источник сообщения, на связь с другими сообщениями и т. д., не могут стоять в начале основного предложения.

Вставные конструкции могут оформляться как члены предложения или предикативные части сложного предложения, но могут в синтаксическом отношении выступать как “чужеродное тело” в составе основного предложения; могут быть включены при помощи союзов и союзных слов или же без их помощи. Вставные конструкции выделяются паузами, произносятся с понижением тона и убыстрением темпа. В жаркое летнее утро (это было в исходе июля) разбудили нас ранее обыкновенного (А к с а к о в). Отец лишился обыкновенной своей твердости и горесть его (обыкновенно немая) изливалась в горьких жалобах (Пушкин). Он не мог отказаться от места или, скорее, звания (потому что он ничего не делал), которое доставил ему князь Василий (Л. Толстой). Вашей сестре (или сестрам, если они обе в Москве) привет и пожелание счастья (Ч е х о в). **Он был ранен (легко), потом женился, потом уехал за границу** (Короленко).

Специально выделяю последний пример. Там наречие "легко", у Вас - "пока".

Comment: В каком месте точку ставить?
И если не трудно, можно пример  употребления? Я в толк взять не могу, с каких пор "пока, во всяком случае" стало **оборотом**.  
ЗЫ Ну shamov понятно, он за речью не следит, но вы-то?!

Comment: Видимо, имеется в виду случай, когда конструкция идёт в конце. Точка уместна только в таком варианте. Я же имел в виду случай, когда конструкция вставляется после слова "привели". И тогда получаются две запятых вокруг слова "пока". Причём первая появляется только из-за "во всяком случае", к которому даже не примыкает. Без него она не нужна.

Comment: Я имею в виду, что хочу, наконец, увидеть фразу, в которой "пока, во всяком случае" было бы обротом, а не вырванным из конетекста куском, лишенным прямой синтаксичекской связи.

Comment: Извините,  behemothus,  но я использовала не слово  "оборот" , а выражение "присоединительная конструкция".  Она  может присоединяться без каких - либо специальных слов. Поэтому я согласна, что оборота здесь нет. Да. я имела в виду конструкцию в конце предложения. Что-то вроде "Я не могу дать ответ, пока, во всяком случае".

Shamov! Присоединяюсь к просьбе дать предложение целиком.

Comment: @Ларf, начет оборота я shamov'у отвечал. Но суть не в этом. Можете говорить о присоединительной констпукции, но так, чтобы к ней относилось и само слово "пока". Пока же (извините за каламбур) я вижу здесь сочетание обособляемого оборота (скорее всего, как вариант - члена предложения с наречным значением, тогда не обособляется) и независимого от этого оборота наречия или союза "пока" (вряд ли "пока здесь" частица). Вариантов много, но все всесте - ну никак не идиная кеонструкцимя, чем её не обзови.

Comment: Что касается вашего примера, то он производит впечатления чисто разговорного, остсюда и возможные неоднозначности в синтаксисе и пунктуации. Но все-таки. Запятая перед "пока" - в лучшем случае интонационная. После "пока" запятая необходима, т.к. "во всяком случае" здесь обособляемый оборот.

Comment: Конечно, слово пока входит в присоединительную конструкцию .

Comment: Дополнил вопрос. Особенно интересно про тире. Этот вариант мне нравится больше всего.

Comment: Не понимаю, что еще нужно дополнить в ответ?

Comment: Возможно, что ничего. Я не уверен, что есть явно сформулированное правило о том, что приставные конструкции можно выделять с помощью тире, а речевые обороты - только запятыми. Мне просто интуитивно кажется, что должен быть какой-то способ разделить иронию и уточнение. Тире подходит идеально. Оно почти не тормозит темп речи, и поэтому подходит для уточнения. А об запятую мы как бы спотыкаемся, вынуждены делать хорошую паузу, поэтому этот вариант подходит для ироничного оборота.

Comment: Мне нравится предложение Ларf  с точкой :"Предпринятые меры не привели к ожидаемому результату. Пока, во всяком случае". Вот только насчет присоединительной конструкции не все ясно. Насколько я помню, подобный способ оформления мысли называется парцелляцией. Разве не так? А присоединительные конструкции  входят в состав предложения и обычно отделяются запятой от основной части предложения

Comment: Верно.Парцелляция. Терминология разных разделов.

Answer (score 4):

Сначала по поводу "***во всяком случае***":
6) **Сочетание *во всяком случае* является вводным и обособляется, если имеет ограничительно-оценочное значение:

 *Во всяком случае, ***фамилия его была не Акундин (А.Т.); Я,*** во всяком случае, ***этого не утверждал; Она,*** во всяком случае***, в этом деле не замешана; Эти сведения,*** во всяком случае в короткий срок,*** проверить будет трудно (выделяется весь оборот). 
В значении же «при любых обстоятельствах» это сочетание вводным не является: …Во всяком случае он никогда не оставит прежнего своего питомца (П.); Вы во всяком случае будете поставлены в известность о ходе дела; Я твёрдо был уверен, что во всяком случае встречу его сегодня у мамы (Дост.).(http://www.ngebooks.com/book_27869_chapter_32_x_x_x.html)

А теперь по поводу запятой после "пока".

**Если вводное слово (сочетание) стоит в начале или в конце обособленного оборота (обособления, уточнения, пояснения, присоединения), то никаким знаком препинания от оборота оно не отделяется** (http://www.ngebooks.com/book_27869_chapter_32_x_x_x.html).
Знаки, по-моему, надо поставить так:
***Предпринятые меры не привели, пока во всяком случае, к ожидаемому результату.*** .
А если выделить конструкцию  двумя тире, что очень даже возможно, то получится так:
***Предпринятые меры не привели - пока во всяком случае - к ожидаемому результату.***

Comment: Все верно. Прошу прощения за невнимательность.

Answer (score 0):

предпринятые меры - так нельзя говорить, так как меры только принимают.

Comment: Предпринятые меры не привели к ожидаемому результату - пока во всяком случае. Возможен такой и такой вариант: Предпринятые меры не привели к ожидаемому результату, пока во всяком случае.После тире (запятой) стоит присоединительная конструкция, в конце которой вводное сочетание, которое в конце и в начале обособленных оборотов не отделяется от него запятой. Например: Я опять промолчал, должно быть от изумления (Паустовский).

Comment: "1772 году произошло возмущение в их главном городке. Причиною тому были строгие меры, предпринятые генералом-майором Траубенбергом" (с) А. С. Пушкин. Капитанская дочка.

"Чиновники положили наконец потолковать окончательно об этом предмете и решить по крайней мере, что и как им делать, и какие меры предпринять" (с) Н. В. Гоголь. Мертвые души

Comment: А я поверила Марине Королевой 

М. – Собственно, вся эта красота должна была служить единственной цели: показать, что меры можно только принимать. А вот предпринимать можно чуть больше: можно предпринять усилия, можно шаги какие-то предпринять, можно вообще ЧТО-НИБУДЬ предпринять… 
    О. – Только не меры! 
    М. – Да, только не меры.

Comment: на сайте http://www.rg.ru/plus/koroleva/

Comment: У Гоголя последняя запятая по какому правилу?